# ¿Como obtener coordenadas reales del punto en el que me encuentro?

Tags: java, android-studio, gps

Tengo el siguiente código para obtener las coordenadas cada vez que ingreso en la activity, funciona bien, sin embargo he notado que las coordenadas que se visualizan no son las reales del punto en el que me encuentro, siempre debo entrar dos o tres veces para que muestre las coordenadas reales en el activity.

En el código yo uso **getLastKnownLocation**, sin embargo buscando en internet, he encontrado que existe **requestSingleUpdate** y **getCurrentLocation** para obtener las coordenadas reales del punto en el que me encuentro.

Me pueden decir por favor como implementar el uso de  **requestSingleUpdate** / **getCurrentLocation** en mi código.

En mi código no uso **onLocationChanged()** porque unicamente necesito las coordenadas del momento en que ingreso a la activity, ademas el uso de **onLocationChanged** consume mucha batería.

Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

Activity1.java

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity1.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity1.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity1.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 123);
                            }

ubicacion = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
Location loc = ubicacion.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

if (loc != null) {
  latitud_actual = loc.getLatitude();
  longitud_actual = loc.getLongitude();
   
  textlat.setText(String.valueof(latitud_actual));
  textlon.setText(String.valueof(longitud_actual));

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En realidad si **tienes que usar [onLocationChanged()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener#onLocationChanged(java.util.List%3Candroid.location.Location%3E)), ya que en este método obtendrá la primera lectura de tu geolocalización.**

> [onLocationChanged()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener#onLocationChanged(java.util.List%3Candroid.location.Location%3E)) Se llama cuando la ubicación ha cambiado y
> las ubicaciones se entregan en lotes. La implementación predeterminada
> llama a onLocationChanged(android.location.Location) con todas las
> ubicaciones del lote. Siempre se garantiza que la lista de ubicaciones
> no estará vacía y siempre se garantizará que estará ordenada desde la
> ubicación más antigua hasta la más reciente (de modo que la ubicación
> más temprana del lote esté en el índice 0 de la lista y la última
> ubicación del lote). está en el tamaño de índice-1 en la lista).

Implementa el método y obtén los valores de latitud y longitud:

```
fun onLocationChanged(location: Location) {

     latitud_actual = location.latitude
     longitud_actual = location.longitude

 }
```

Comment: Gracias @Jorgesys por responder, una duda, yo necesito las coordenadas SOLO UNA VEZ, al entrar en una activity, ¿una vez obtenidas las nuevas coordenadas que entrega onLocationChanged(), hay forma de cancelar la clase (Obtener_coordenadas) donde esta onLocationcChanged() para que no siga funcionando y descargando la bateria? gracias por tu colaboración

Comment: Ok @Linamar , entiendo lo que deseas, en este caso si solo una vez deseas requerir una ocasión la geolocalización, puedes hacer uso de locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener), esto provocará que puedas requerir actualizaciones de tu geolocalización, puedes guardar un valor en preferencias para indicar a la app no llamar locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(), Si deseas realizar otra pregunta con esta duda, podemos hacer una respuesta más detallada para que puedas realizar sin problema lo que deseas.

Comment: Ok @Jorgesys voy a hacer ya mismo una nueva pregunta del mismo tema, tratando de ser mas explicito. gracias